# Can someone tell me what exactly this means?

Tags: meaning

Can someone tell me what exactly this means?

> "While a transcendent vocabulary is laudable, one must nevertheless keep incessant surveillance against such loquacious, effusive, voluble verbosity that the calculated objective of communication becomes ensconced in obscurity."

by Frank L. Visco from *Reader's Digest* (1986)

Comment: It's good to know lots of long words, but it's usually better to use short ones.

Comment: "The goal of communication is not merely to be understood, but to make it impossible to be misunderstood." - Quintilian (paraphrased)

Comment: Visco used the same "self-referentially satirical" style in a couple of dozen recommendations featured [in Reader's Digest that same year.](http://www.art-xy.com/2013/03/how-to-write-good-by-frank-l-visco-and.html) It's a *joke*, not worth analysing here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a satirical comment.  It simply means to keep your writing unpretentious. Remove superfluous words and be concise, otherwise the reader will become confused.